# Limit result from inner join query to 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, having-clause

My query is giving me result from grouped data but now I want only two rows

I have tried `HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2` but issue is is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

my query is

```
select f.CompanyName, f.EmployeeCity, f.PrioritySL ,f.EmployeeSeniorityLevel ,f.EmployeeID
from (
   select ConcatKey, min(PrioritySL) as PSL 
   from dbo.WalkerItContacts group by ConcatKey 
) as x inner join dbo.WalkerItContacts as f on f.ConcatKey = x.ConcatKey and f.PrioritySL = x.PSL
where f.PrioritySL != '10'
```

Company apple have 9 records I want only 2 records

my data

`company name     priority
    a                 10
    a                  1
    a                  3
    b                  2
    b                  4
    b                  3
    b                  5
    c                  1
    c                  10
    c                  2`

my expected data

`company name         priority
      a                   1
      a                   3
      b                   2
      b                   3
      c                   1
      c                   2`

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: It should be random 2 records out of 9?

Comment: yes random 2 records

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'top 2' clause  to the outer query:

```
select top 2 f.CompanyName, f.EmployeeCity, f.PrioritySL ,f.EmployeeSeniorityLevel ,f.EmployeeID
    from (
       select ConcatKey, min(PrioritySL) as PSL 
       from dbo.WalkerItContacts group by ConcatKey 
    ) as x inner join dbo.WalkerItContacts as f on f.ConcatKey = x.ConcatKey and f.PrioritySL = x.PSL
    where f.PrioritySL != '10' 
and f.CompanyName= 'Apple'
```

will give you two rows. Add a order clause by in the outer query so you can control which two rows are returned.

Comment: thankyou for answer but your query is giving me only two   rows out from my all company rows

Comment: You have a where statement which limits it to Apple. If you want all companies drop the where f.companyname='Apple' and add a group by f.companyname

Comment: yes sir i just  use where clause to check result  but in actual what i want i just edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You can phrase this more succinctly and with better performance as:

```
select top (2) wic.*
from (select wic,
             rank() over (partition by CompanyName, ConcatKey order by PrioritySL) as seqnum
      from dbo.WalkerItContacts wic
     ) wic
where seqnum = 1 and
      wic.PrioritySL <> 10 and
      wic.CompanyName = 'Apple';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve your problem using the ROW_NUMBER() function to count the rows and filter it in the WHERE clause to only show 2 rows per group.

I think something like this might work for you:

```
SELECT rownum, f.CompanyName, f.EmployeeCity, f.PrioritySL, 
                                               f.EmployeeSeniorityLevel, f.EmployeeID
FROM ( SELECT ConcatKey, MIN(PrioritySL) AS PSL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
                                                             f.CompanyName) AS rownum
       FROM dbo.WalkerItContacts
       GROUP BY ConcatKey) AS x
                    INNER JOIN dbo.WalkerItContacts AS f ON f.ConcatKey = x.ConcatKey 
                                                             AND f.PrioritySL = x.PSL
WHERE f.PrioritySL != '10' AND rownum <= 2
ORDER BY f.CompanyName ASC;
```

Hope this helps some.

Comment: The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.
 i am getting this error

Comment: Ah kk, sorry about. Try adding an ORDER BY clause to the ROW_NUMBER function on a column that would still make it non deterministic like OVER(PARTITION BY f.CompanyName ORDER BY ConcatKey) as rownum

Comment: sir still not luck getting error ->The multi-part identifier "f.CompanyName" could not be bound.

Comment: Hmm kk, so that usually means that the source table cannot be found, in this case table f in the subquery. Is the CompanyName column also in the dbo.WalkerItContacts table? If so, we might be able to tweak the code in the subquery to OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY ConcatKey).